# List items not staying activated master/detail flow

Tags: android, arraylist, android-listfragment

I've modified the master/detail flow template to display my own list array. However, now, when I click an item in the listfragment, it isn't staying activated.

Here is the code to the listfragment.

```
package com.example.sample;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListFragment;

/**
 * A list fragment representing a list of Courses. This fragment also supports
 * tablet devices by allowing list items to be given an 'activated' state upon
 * selection. This helps indicate which item is currently being viewed in a
 *{@link CourseDetailFragment}.
 * <p>
 * Activities containing this fragment MUST implement the {@link Callbacks}
 * interface.
 */
public class CourseListFragment extends SherlockListFragment {

private static String courseName;
ArrayList<String> courseItems;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
/**
 * The serialization (saved instance state) Bundle key representing the
 * activated item position. Only used on tablets.
 */
private static final String STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION = "activated_position";

/**
 * The fragment's current callback object, which is notified of list item
 * clicks.
 */
private Callbacks mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;

/**
 * The current activated item position. Only used on tablets.
 */
private int mActivatedPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;

/**
 * A callback interface that all activities containing this fragment must
 * implement. This mechanism allows activities to be notified of item
 * selections.
 */
public interface Callbacks {
    /**
     * Callback for when an item has been selected.
     */
    public void onItemSelected(String id);
}

/**
 * A dummy implementation of the {@link Callbacks} interface that does
 * nothing. Used only when this fragment is not attached to an activity.
 */
private static Callbacks sDummyCallbacks = new Callbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(String id) {
    }
};

/**
 * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
 * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
 */
public CourseListFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    courseItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, courseItems);
    // TODO: replace with a real list adapter.
    int layout = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) ? android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1
            : android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    // Restore the previously serialized activated item position.
    if (savedInstanceState != null
            && savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION)) {
        setActivatedPosition(savedInstanceState
                .getInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION));
    }
}
public void addCourse(String courseName) {
    courseItems.add(courseName);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // Activities containing this fragment must implement its callbacks.
    if (!(activity instanceof Callbacks)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Activity must implement fragment's callbacks.");
    }

    mCallbacks = (Callbacks) activity;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

    // Reset the active callbacks interface to the dummy implementation.
    mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);
    // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
    // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
    mCallbacks.onItemSelected(null);

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if (mActivatedPosition != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
        // Serialize and persist the activated item position.
        outState.putInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION, mActivatedPosition);
    }
}

/**
 * Turns on activate-on-click mode. When this mode is on, list items will be
 * given the 'activated' state when touched.
 */
public void setActivateOnItemClick(boolean activateOnItemClick) {
    // When setting CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE, ListView will automatically
    // give items the 'activated' state when touched.
    getListView().setChoiceMode(
            activateOnItemClick ? ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE
                    : ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
}

public void setActivatedPosition(int position) {
    if (position == ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
        getListView().setItemChecked(mActivatedPosition, false);
    } else {
        getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
    }

    mActivatedPosition = position;
}
}
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are always passing in `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` into your list adapter. That's a layout that does *not* use a selector with support for the activated state. However, it seems you're almost there, as the snippet suggests you just overlooked one of your own TODOs:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, courseItems);
// TODO: replace with a real list adapter.
int layout = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) ? android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1 : android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
```

Reorder those two statements and use the `int layout` as input for the adapter. For example:

```
int layout = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) ? android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1 : android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), layout, courseItems);
```

On devices running Honeycomb or newer that should give you the list selector with activated state.